# Resizing VMDK Size

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have created a VM with a expanding VMDK set to a 500GB, however, I want to change the size of the VMDK to 40GB, is that possible?

I have searched solutions but most of it are just "compacting" the VMDK (I mean removing fragments) and also expanding the VMDK, but none for my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VMware Converter Standalone](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_0) will let you change the hard drive from thin provisioned to flat (full size allocated).  This will create a VM with a 500GB disk, however.

You can use a Linux LiveCD with GParted to resize the partition, however you don't mention the OS, but procedure varies depending on the partition type.

Comment: I assume you mean to use the partition program inside the VM right? But that would only affect the partition; as far as the guest system (BIOS) is concerned, the drive is still the same size as before because that is what the VM software is telling it.